# Logistic regression in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic

Still on running logistic regression models and would like to ask a few questions around it.

**Question 1**:
Is there a simple way of getting the p-values of each independent factor in a logistic regression model. For example, I am running this model:

```
mymod3 <- as.formula(surv~as.factor(tdate)+as.factor(sline)+as.factor(pgrp)
                                          +as.factor(weight5)+as.factor(backfat5)
                                          +as.factor(srect2)+as.factor(bcs)
                                          +as.factor(agit)+as.factor(uscore)
                                          +as.factor(loco)+as.factor(teat2)
                                          +as.factor(uscoref)+as.factor(colos)
                                          +as.factor(tb5)+as.factor(nerve)
                                          +as.factor(feed5)+as.factor(fos)
                                          +as.factor(gest3)+as.factor(int3)
                                          +as.factor(psex)+as.factor(bwt5)
                                          +as.factor(presp2)+as.factor(mtone2)
                                          +as.factor(pscolor)+as.factor(pmstain)
                                          +as.factor(pshiv)+as.factor(ppscore)
                                          +as.factor(pincis)+as.factor(prectem5)
                                          +as.factor(pcon12)+as.factor(crum5)
                                          +as.factor(pindx5))

sofNoMis3 <- apf[which(complete.cases(apf[,all.vars(mymod3)])),]
FulMod3 <- glm(mymod3,family=binomial(link="logit"),data=sofNoMis3)
summary(FulMod3)
```

I am using this to look at the significant level of each factor:

```
anova(FulMod3,test="Chisq")
```

and got this:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: surv

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


                    Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                                 7791     7096.2              
as.factor(tdate)    15    50.71      7776     7045.4 9.215e-06 ***
as.factor(sline)     1    13.90      7775     7031.5 0.0001924 ***
as.factor(pgrp)      3     8.83      7772     7022.7 0.0316335 *  
as.factor(weight5)   4     7.18      7768     7015.5 0.1268943    
as.factor(backfat5)  4     3.86      7764     7011.7 0.4258074    
as.factor(srect2)    1     0.15      7763     7011.5 0.6987832    
as.factor(bcs)       3     6.46      7760     7005.1 0.0910745 .  
as.factor(agit)      2    13.44      7758     6991.6 0.0012075 ** 
as.factor(uscore)    2     2.16      7756     6989.5 0.3401845    
as.factor(loco)      2     1.58      7754     6987.9 0.4530983    
as.factor(teat2)     2    25.45      7752     6962.4 2.980e-06 ***
as.factor(uscoref)   2     0.48      7750     6962.0 0.7861675    
as.factor(colos)     1     1.06      7749     6960.9 0.3034592    
as.factor(tb5)       4    49.22      7745     6911.7 5.265e-10 ***
as.factor(nerve)     2     0.99      7743     6910.7 0.6105452    
as.factor(feed5)     4    11.79      7739     6898.9 0.0190170 *  
as.factor(fos)       1    47.10      7738     6851.8 6.732e-12 ***
as.factor(gest3)     2    22.60      7736     6829.2 1.235e-05 ***
as.factor(int3)      2     6.61      7734     6822.6 0.0367298 *  
as.factor(psex)      1     9.50      7733     6813.1 0.0020493 ** 
as.factor(bwt5)      4   348.42      7729     6464.7 < 2.2e-16 ***
as.factor(presp2)    1   106.23      7728     6358.4 < 2.2e-16 ***
as.factor(mtone2)    1    34.13      7727     6324.3 5.146e-09 ***
as.factor(pscolor)   1    12.57      7726     6311.7 0.0003928 ***
as.factor(pmstain)   1     0.30      7725     6311.4 0.5845095    
as.factor(pshiv)     1    32.29      7724     6279.2 1.328e-08 ***
as.factor(ppscore)   1    16.71      7723     6262.4 4.351e-05 ***
as.factor(pincis)    1     0.02      7722     6262.4 0.8892848    
as.factor(prectem5)  4   126.06      7718     6136.4 < 2.2e-16 ***
as.factor(pcon12)    1    17.88      7717     6118.5 2.350e-05 ***
as.factor(crum5)     4    15.25      7713     6103.2 0.0042137 ** 
as.factor(pindx5)    4    25.58      7709     6077.6 3.838e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

but it does not always agree with the final model after applying backward elimination:

Example:

these three factors were not significant above but they still appeared in the final model below

```
as.factor(weight5)   4     7.18      7768     7015.5 0.1268943    
as.factor(backfat5)  4     3.86      7764     7011.7 0.4258074    
as.factor(srect2)    1     0.15      7763     7011.5 0.6987832    

step(FulMod3,direction="backward",trace=FALSE)
```

which gives:

```
Call:  glm(formula = surv ~ as.factor(tdate) + as.factor(pgrp) + as.factor(weight5) + 
    as.factor(backfat5) + as.factor(srect2) + as.factor(agit) + 
    as.factor(uscore) + as.factor(teat2) + as.factor(uscoref) + 
    as.factor(fos) + as.factor(gest3) + as.factor(int3) + as.factor(psex) + 
    as.factor(bwt5) + as.factor(presp2) + as.factor(mtone2) + 
    as.factor(pscolor) + as.factor(pshiv) + as.factor(ppscore) + 
    as.factor(prectem5) + as.factor(pcon12) + as.factor(pindx5), 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = sofNoMis3)

Coefficients:
               (Intercept)  as.factor(tdate)2009-09-11  as.factor(tdate)2009-09-15  as.factor(tdate)2009-09-18  as.factor(tdate)2009-09-22  
                   1.34799                     0.18414                    -0.19490                    -0.15552                    -0.16822  
as.factor(tdate)2009-09-25  as.factor(tdate)2009-09-29  as.factor(tdate)2010-01-26  as.factor(tdate)2010-01-29  as.factor(tdate)2010-02-02  
                   0.60046                     0.80784                    -1.03442                    -1.30562                    -1.01486  
as.factor(tdate)2010-02-05  as.factor(tdate)2010-02-09  as.factor(tdate)2010-02-12  as.factor(tdate)2010-02-16  as.factor(tdate)2010-02-19  
                  -1.04438                    -0.89311                    -1.06260                    -0.79833                    -1.09651  
as.factor(tdate)2010-02-23            as.factor(pgrp)2            as.factor(pgrp)3            as.factor(pgrp)4         as.factor(weight5)2  
                  -0.55411                     0.12659                    -0.04727                     0.21817                    -0.22592  
       as.factor(weight5)3         as.factor(weight5)4         as.factor(weight5)5        as.factor(backfat5)2        as.factor(backfat5)3  
                  -0.10143                    -0.31562                    -0.37656                    -0.19883                    -0.01188  
      as.factor(backfat5)4        as.factor(backfat5)5          as.factor(srect2)2            as.factor(agit)2            as.factor(agit)3  
                   0.08293                    -0.17116                    -0.18201                    -0.49145                    -0.36659  
        as.factor(uscore)2          as.factor(uscore)3           as.factor(teat2)2           as.factor(teat2)3         as.factor(uscoref)2  
                  -0.12265                     0.15334                     0.16575                     0.21520                     0.24166  
       as.factor(uscoref)3             as.factor(fos)2           as.factor(gest3)2           as.factor(gest3)3            as.factor(int3)2  
                  -0.24363                    -0.29506                     0.09747                     0.81894                    -0.25595  
          as.factor(int3)3            as.factor(psex)2            as.factor(bwt5)2            as.factor(bwt5)3            as.factor(bwt5)4  
                  -1.21086                     0.20025                     0.30753                     0.29614                     0.56753  
          as.factor(bwt5)5          as.factor(presp2)2          as.factor(mtone2)2         as.factor(pscolor)2           as.factor(pshiv)2  
                   0.86479                    -0.29270                    -0.40912                    -0.72782                    -0.33848  
       as.factor(ppscore)2        as.factor(prectem5)2        as.factor(prectem5)3        as.factor(prectem5)4        as.factor(prectem5)5  
                  -0.25958                     0.73842                     0.77476                     0.92158                     0.96269  
        as.factor(pcon12)2          as.factor(pindx5)2          as.factor(pindx5)3          as.factor(pindx5)4          as.factor(pindx5)5  
                   0.38119                     0.43199                     0.44496                     0.73458                     0.59771  

Degrees of Freedom: 7791 Total (i.e. Null);  7732 Residual
Null Deviance:      7096 
Residual Deviance: 6102         AIC: 6222
```

**Question 2**:

I would like to calculate the standard errors of the odds ratio of each factor level

```
exp(NewMod3$coefficients)  #Odds ratios
```

**Question 3:**

Lastly, to tell whether the levels of each factor are significantly different or not

```
               (Intercept) as.factor(tdate)2009-09-11 as.factor(tdate)2009-09-15 as.factor(tdate)2009-09-18 as.factor(tdate)2009-09-22 
                 3.8496863                  1.2021883                  0.8229141                  0.8559688                  0.8451676 
as.factor(tdate)2009-09-25 as.factor(tdate)2009-09-29 as.factor(tdate)2010-01-26 as.factor(tdate)2010-01-29 as.factor(tdate)2010-02-02 
                 1.8229563                  2.2430525                  0.3554327                  0.2710041                  0.3624544 
as.factor(tdate)2010-02-05 as.factor(tdate)2010-02-09 as.factor(tdate)2010-02-12 as.factor(tdate)2010-02-16 as.factor(tdate)2010-02-19 
                 0.3519109                  0.4093819                  0.3455567                  0.4500787                  0.3340336 
as.factor(tdate)2010-02-23           as.factor(pgrp)2           as.factor(pgrp)3           as.factor(pgrp)4        as.factor(weight5)2 
                 0.5745817                  1.1349500                  0.9538339                  1.2437928                  0.7977835 
       as.factor(weight5)3        as.factor(weight5)4        as.factor(weight5)5       as.factor(backfat5)2       as.factor(backfat5)3 
                 0.9035410                  0.7293337                  0.6862173                  0.8196866                  0.9881871 
      as.factor(backfat5)4       as.factor(backfat5)5         as.factor(srect2)2           as.factor(agit)2           as.factor(agit)3 
                 1.0864697                  0.8426844                  0.8335940                  0.6117399                  0.6930936 
        as.factor(uscore)2         as.factor(uscore)3          as.factor(teat2)2          as.factor(teat2)3        as.factor(uscoref)2 
                 0.8845715                  1.1657233                  1.1802836                  1.2401126                  1.2733576 
       as.factor(uscoref)3            as.factor(fos)2          as.factor(gest3)2          as.factor(gest3)3           as.factor(int3)2 
                 0.7837753                  0.7444886                  1.1023798                  2.2681046                  0.7741829 
          as.factor(int3)3           as.factor(psex)2           as.factor(bwt5)2           as.factor(bwt5)3           as.factor(bwt5)4 
                 0.2979401                  1.2217088                  1.3600609                  1.3446543                  1.7639063 
          as.factor(bwt5)5         as.factor(presp2)2         as.factor(mtone2)2        as.factor(pscolor)2          as.factor(pshiv)2 
                 2.3745019                  0.7462454                  0.6642372                  0.4829602                  0.7128545 
       as.factor(ppscore)2       as.factor(prectem5)2       as.factor(prectem5)3       as.factor(prectem5)4       as.factor(prectem5)5 
                 0.7713779                  2.0926314                  2.1700692                  2.5132469                  2.6187261 
        as.factor(pcon12)2         as.factor(pindx5)2         as.factor(pindx5)3         as.factor(pindx5)4         as.factor(pindx5)5 
                 1.4640265                  1.5403203                  1.5604231                  2.0845978                  1.8179532
```

Example:

I would like to have a table like this:

```
Factor           levels  Odds ratio

Parity group      (1)    1.00±standard error   a
                   2     1.50±standard errror  b
                  3-4    1.17±standard error   c
                   >5    1.19±standard error   c
```

I would really appreciate your help on these 3 areas.

Baz

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:  The `step()` function does elimination using AIC; `anova(FulMod3, test="Chisq")` is, I believe, equivalent to likelihood ratio tests.  Different statistics, so different results.  You probably shouldn't be fitting a model using stepwise elimination in the first place.  Variable selection is not trivial; there are plenty of other questions on this site with better info than I could give you, so I'd recommend checking those out.

Question 2: Odds ratios aren't symmetric, so I don't think an exponentiated standard error is going to be meaningful.  But you can skip right to the confidence interval, if that's what you're looking for: `exp(confint(FulMod3))`.

Question 3: Not quite sure what you're asking - isn't this covered by `anova(FulMod3, test = "Chisq")`?